# How to block Snap update notifications on XFCE?

Tags: updates, snap, xfce, notification

Snap keeps telling me to close my apps so it can update, but then promptly doesn't update them. I'm extremely irritated and just want to **filter Snap notifications out while other notifications remain** so I can work.

There doesn't seem to be an easy way to disable Snap auto updates, so I'm wondering if there's a way to prevent the notification from popping up on XFCE.

Thanks!

Comment: I too am looking for an answer to this. I have tried disabling the notification in Settings:Notifications:Apps, but it still appears on my desktop. I am not interested in fiddling with refresh.hold or any of the snap internals. I would like it if it automatically updated, say, when I reboot or when I run apt, or whatever. I wouldn't even mind if it auto-magically updated and told me to restart the browser. But I don't want to see the notification. It is a distraction.

Answer (score 4):

**Update: You cannot do this, since io.snapcraft.SessionAgent sends notifications at high priority, which goes through Do Not Disturb and filters**. As much as I dislike being "that comment", your best bet is to not use Snap.

If Snap followed the notification rules, you could disable via `io.snapcraft.SessionAgent` from being able to send Notifications. You can do that from Settings -> Notifications -> Applications, and toggling `io.snapcraft.SessionAgent`.

Comment: Snapd sets the priority based on how much time you have until it force-updates. However, `xfce4-notify` does not support the "priority" field and only looks at the message timeout. Snapd always sets the timeout at 0, and for some reason `xfce4-notify` interprets this as a "CRITICAL" message and disregards the filter.

Comment: The behavior of `xfce4-notify` is not according to [the spec](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/notification-spec/notification-spec-latest.html). According to the spec, the timeout should only change how long the message is shown, not the priority of the message.

Comment: Moreover, the Gnome and KDE notifications settings don't use "urgency" to decide whether to show a notification of a filtered app. It's clear that XFCE is the one not following the rules.

Answer (score 0):

I use Ubuntu 18 and the following command disabled these notifications:

> snap set core experimental.refresh-app-awareness=false

[Source](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/refresh-app-awareness-call-for-testing/29123)

Comment: This only works temporarily, notifications come back

Comment: That's unfortunate to hear... For me, these notifications have not returned since I used the command many months ago. Maybe more settings are involved to to block these notifications. Unfortunately I'm not experienced enough in Linux to know what they might be. I hope my humble contribution to this thread might help somebody defeat this menace in the future.